# Is there a clean way to determine if a RandomAccessFile is read-only?

Tags: java

I'm looking for a "good" way to determine if a [RandomAccessFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) is read-only

Non-"good" ways include:

- Using reflection to read the value of the "rw" field (not implementation independant)
- Read a byte, seek backward one, write the byte (not threadsafe)

I have tried writing an empty byte array but the call succeeds regardless of whether or not the RandomAccessFile is constructed in read-only or read-write mode.

The one viable approach I've discovered so far is to get a [FileChannel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) and then attempt to create a read-write map.

```
RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("someFile.txt", "r");

raf.getChannel().map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 0);
```

In this example, the attempt to map throws a NonWritableChannelException which could then be caught and used to indicate that the RandomAccessFile is read-only.

However, I have a few concerns with the above approach.

1. The API does not currently provide a way to free memory maps, it's handled by the Garbage Collector, and on some operating system (e.g. Windows) a file can not be deleted while part of it is memory mapped 

   (NOTE: *I have hope that creating a map with a size=0 and position=0 might avoid the Windows mapping restriction but I haven't tested it yet*)
2. According to the [FileChannel.map()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#map-java.nio.channels.FileChannel.MapMode-long-long-) documentation, creating a map is a somewhat expensive operation

Comment: Here is a good way: Have another variable specifying/remembering open mode. Or just a boolean `readonly` variable, if that's all you want to remember. --- Of course, you might want to question your design, if you need to know this and it's not implied by context.

Answer (score 0):

Get the `FileChannel` and try to create a lock. It will fail if the RAF is read-only. Why is another issue.

But I agree with @Andreas. This is a question you shouldn't have to ask. Your application should be able to tell itself how it opened a file without resort to trickery.